# reboot android and take screenshot of current screen programmatically

Tags: java, android, screenshot, reboot

*Hello*

Is there any way to reboot and take screenshot of android?

`Settings.System` isn't working for me.

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 200);
```

And, is there any way to take screenshot of current device screen, from application/service?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to the relevant question you were looking at? Also, two distinct questions should be asked as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to reboot android programmatically?

Unless your app is signed by the system key, no.

> Is there any way to take screenshot of current device screen, from application?

On most non rooted devices this isn't possible, but on some you may be able to parse the framebuffer if it is accessible (it isn't on the majority of devices).